# add data to dojo datagrid

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, dojo

I have a couple of questions related to dojo. Firstly I have an example I copied from online and ran it and it works perfectly. By the way I am working on a web application in visual studio 2010. It runs fine but my question is that I use the urls (version 1.5) from the ajax.googleapis.com and it works but as soon as I use the src="/folder/dojo.js.uncompressed.js" with the local copy (version 1.7.1) in my folder in my web app, it doesn't work. Any ideas about this.

The second question is using the datagrid example but instead of hard coding the values for the datagrid; I want to pass the results of a sql query from a database to the datagrid. Does anyone have ideas on this?

Here is code showing an attempt to use a locally stored file:

```
<title>The Simplest Dojo DataGrid Example of All Time</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
   href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  href="/Styles/Grid.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojox/grid/
  resources/claroGrid.css" />

 </head>
 <body class="claro">
 <div style="width: 600px; height: 200px">
    <table id="billsGrid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th field="number">Number</th>
                <th field="name">Name</th>
                <th field="position">Position</th>
                <th field="victories" width="180px">Super Bowl Victories</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="/Styles/dojo.js.uncompresses.js"
       djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     dojo.ready(function () {
     var theGreatestTeamOfAllTime = {
        items: [{
            "number": "12",
            "name": "Jim Kelly",
            "position": "QB",
            "victories": "0"
        },
             {
                 "number": "34",
                 "name": "Thurman Thomas",
                 "position": "RB",
                 "victories": "0"
             },
             {
                 "number": "89",
                 "name": "Steve Tasker",
                 "position": "WR",
                 "victories": "0"
             },
        {
            "number": "78",
            "name": "Bruce Smith",
            "position": "DE",
            "victories": "0"
        }
           ],
        identifier: "number"
     };

     var dataStore =
    new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore(
    { data: theGreatestTeamOfAllTime }
    );
    var grid = dijit.byId("billsGrid");
    grid.setStore(dataStore);
  });
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

This does not work with jscript errors cropping up.

could not load dojox/grid/DataGrid.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work locally, examine your djConfig and the script includes for dojo to ensure paths are correct, especially the baseUrl

```
djConfig = {
            parseOnLoad: true,
            baseUrl: "../dojoroot/dojo/"
           }
```

ALso make sure you are including the correct stylesheets (all includes and stylesheets must point to the same dojo version)

Examine the Net tab in firebug to see any errors in urls

regarding your second question, dojo has a concept of datastores - these are client (javascript) side holders of data. Your server-side can return the query result in JSON (preferred), XML or any other format.
The client (javascript/html) can use AJAX to fetch this data and render it in a datagrid.

dojo has fancy stores such as queryreadstore that supports paging/lazyloading

A good place to start is the nightly tests for dojo:

http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/

Comment: sorry for the late response and thanks for you suggestions. Could you help with the syntax of the code as I have been unable to find examples of locally saved dojo files being used. Please see edit above,

Comment: I have posted a follow up answer below (comment has a character limit hence a follow up answer)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I follow:

1) download dojo toolkit from http://dojotoolkit.org/download/

2) install it with your application root. Typically, in my application root directory, I have a directory called dojoroot under which i untar dojo toolkit

3) in your html, head section make sure your css links are pointing to local dojoroot. FOr xample:

4) Make sure your djConfig is correctly set:
djConfig = {
                parseOnLoad: true,
                baseUrl: "../../../dojoroot/dojo/"
            };
note that the baseUrl is important - it is the directory in which dojo.js is located

5) for the dojo.js src include, make sure the path is correct. for example:

If there are errors, your Net tab in firebug will show them - they are usually related to path issues

Comment: great - happy to help. Could you please mark this answer as accepted so it gets recorded as resolved. Thanks

Comment: hi do you know of any easy examples of datagrid. I have copied the source exactly from the examples and still get errors.

Comment: sorry one more quick question; do you have a blog or site where you contribute dojo stuff; your explanation on these things is much better than the dojotoolkit site.